# Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}

Tags: twitter, promise, undefined

I am running this on Twitter via developer tools but I am running into the following error
Promise {: undefined}

Here is what I am currently running

```
function nextUnlike() {
  return document.querySelector('[data-testid="unlike"]')
}

function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function removeAll() {
  let count = 0
  let next = nextUnlike()
  while (next) {
    next.focus()
    next.click()
    console.log(`Unliked ${++count} tweets`)
    await wait(count % 50 === 0 ? 30000 : 2000)
    next = nextUnlike()
  }
  console.log('Out of unlikes, count =', count)
}

removeAll()
```

I'm not sure if this is an error on my end or if it's Twitter blocking this action. Thanks!

I tried running the above code via developer tools on Twitter's website but received the following error
Promise {: undefined}

Comment: That `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}` seems to be the promise returned by `removeAll()`. That in itself is not an error, just a return value. Have you debugged which statements execute? Do you get the `console.log` output?

Comment: The console.log output is 0

Comment: Have you debugged which statements execute?

Comment: No I have not - I am struggling with that part

Comment: Then maybe first concentrate on how to use a debugger. It is a fundamental resource for a coder.

Comment: Overall, the code seems to be fine, but its execution might be hindered by the structure and behavior of the web page being manipulated (in this case, Twitter)